# how to find the template matching accuracy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

i am doing a template matching
now,what i want to do is find the accuracy of template matching
I have done template matching, but how do i get the accuracy
i think i have to subtract the matched region and template image.
how do i achieve this

**CODE**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('image.jpg',0)
img1 = img.copy()
template = cv.imread('template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

method = ['cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED','cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED']
for meth in method:
    img = img1.copy()
    method = eval(meth)

    res = cv.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(res)

    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result')

    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point') 
    plt.show()
```

Comment: opencv has the function absdiff

Answer (score 4):

Please don't use absolute dif or any similar method to calculate accuracy. You already have accuracy values in the variables `min_val, max_val`.

The OpenCV template matching uses [various forms of correlation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#which-are-the-matching-methods-available-in-opencv) to calculate the match. So when you use `cv.matchTemplate(img,template,method)` the value stored in the `res` image is the result of this correlation.

So, when you use `cv.minMaxLoc(res)` you are calculating the minimum and maximum result of this correlation. I simply use `max_val` to tell me how well it has matched. Since both `min_val` and `max_val` are in the range `[-1.0, 1.0]`, if `max_val` is 1.0 I take that as a 100% match, a `max_val` of 0.5 as a 50% match, and so on.

I've tried using a combination of `min_val` and `max_val` to scale the values to get a better understanding, but I found that simply using `max_val` gives me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples of metrics one can use to compare images. Some of them are:

- [SAD: Sum of Absolute Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences)
- [SSD: Sum of Squared Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_deviations_from_the_mean)
- [Cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation)

All these require some elementary operations on the pixel values of the images to compare.