# How to detect similar of object in photo by Python

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, prediction

Currently, I try to develop AI system by Python to matching Sacred object from 2 photo.
The first photo is a high-resolution Sacred object (A) photo capture by DSLR camera.
[image]
The second photo is a Sacred object (A) photo capture by Phone Camera.
[image]

I need the AI system to predict the percentage of similar from 0 - 100%.
I try some methodlogy but I don't get a good result.

Please suggest which methodlogy will be fit to prediction model?
THANK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736154/how-to-check-similarity-of-two-images-that-have-different-pixelization have you checked this?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using `template-matching`

If you use the first image as a template:

- Template image:

---

- [image]
- Source image:

---

- [image]
- Result will be:

---

- [image]

Steps:

---

- 1. Convert both `template` and `source` images to the gray-scale and apply Canny edge detection.

  - ```py
    template = cv2.imread("template_resized.jpg")
    template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
    ```
  - [image]
  - ```py
    source = cv2.imread("source_resized.jpg")
    source = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    source = cv2.Canny(source, 50, 200)
    ```
  - [image]
- 2. Check whether the template matches the source image

  - `result = cv2.matchTemplate(source, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)`
  - We need maximum-value and maximum-value location from the `result`
  - `(_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)`
- 3. Get coordinates and draw the rectangle

  - ```py
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + w) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + h) * r))
    ```
  - Draw Rectangle
  - ```py
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    ```

***Possible Question:*** Why didn't you use the original image size?

---

Answer: Well, `template-matching` works better for small images. Otherwise the result is not satisfactory. If I use the original image size the result will be: [link](https://ibb.co/g9p4HCx)

***Possible Question:*** Why did you use `cv2.TM_CCOEFF`?

---

Answer: It was just an example, you can experiment with the other [parameters](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)

***Possible Question:*** How do I calculate the similarity-percentage using template-matching?

---

Answer: Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840868/how-to-find-the-template-matching-accuracy). As stated you can use the `minMaxLoc`'s output for similarity percentage.

For full code, please look at the [opencv-python tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html).